# Searching encrypted data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have some a database that has a bunch of 'normal' data in it as well as a first and last name which are encrypted.

I have a PHP page which gets that data and in the MySQL statement, orders it by last name.

It then prints the information on the page using a while loop and this page also has a simple first/last name search.

I have two issues I'm not sure how to resolve:

1. How do I order the data by last name, the MySQL statement does an order by  but as the last name is encrypted, the wrong order once decrypted.
2. How do I get my search to work? Currently if the post variable isset, it adds to the MySQL query, but again this queries encrypted data so doesn't work.

I'm guessing I need to get my data out, and pass it into a new array whilst decrypting the names, then sort that array. Then I can also apply my search to that array too.

If the above is correct, I'm not sure how to do it, I've given it ago but I can't figure out how to decrypt my data whilst passing it into a new array. My decrypt function accepts two parameters, the data and the encryption key and I couldn't get an array_walker to work...

I think if I solve the first issue I can figure out how to search.

Please help!!

Comment: Why is the data encrypted at all? If it makes it hard or impossible to actually *work* with the data, you should question this assumption. Secondarily, *how* is it encrypted; can it be decrypted in the database or does it need an external function?

Comment: As @deceze said, we need to firstly know why it is encrypted in the first place.  Is that something you have done intentionally, and if so, why?  If it is for security reasons and you are able to drag it down and decrypt it easily, that suggests its probably not very encrypted anyway (I could be way off there).  Some more details and perhaps an example of some of the encrypted names? Maybe how you encrypted them in the first place.

Comment: You have to decrypt it before searching or ordering, e.g. `ORDER BY decrypt(last_name)` or `WHERE decrypt(last_name) LIKE '%searchstring%'`. This will make queries very slow, since it can't use indexes.

Comment: And even that assumes that the decryption is a MySQL function. If the encryption is done in PHP, you'll have to retrieve *everything*, decrypt it, then do the searching or sorting in the PHP array.

Comment: For the searching, you can encrypt your search term (assuming it's not a `LIKE` operator or anything with wildcards) and then search with the encrypted string. As for ordering, you'll obviously have to decrypt and then order the results. If you can't decrypt in your database then you'll have to do that in PHP... however you like.

Comment: @JNevill Doesn't your searching suggestion assume that one given string always encrypts to the same encrypted string?  I don't believe that's usually the case (with decent encryption).

Comment: That is the assumption. If the encrypted string is salted and the salt isn't static (lets hope if a salt is required here that it isn't static) then obviously that won't work. And yes.. some encryption schemes are deterministic (AES) and other's not so much (RSA... sort of). It just depends on how OP is encrypting. It does sound like this is a job for PHP though...

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the comments, here are some responses: 1) it's encrypted because of the new EU GDPR law, we store the details of parents and children and have been advised the encrypt first and last names in the database. 2) I am doing the encryption and decryption in PHP using a couple of functions. 3) I am happy to go down the array approach, I only need to do this on one admin-only page but I've been struggling so any guidance on doing this so I can order the array and keyword search it would be really helpful! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution, I don't know if it's the best way but as I only needed to search the names I did the following:

I needed to retain my existing foreach that loops through my code and prints in on to the page, so I created a while loop after my sql statement that builds a new array, decrypting my data too:

```
        $array_new = array();

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $FirstName = custom_decrypt($row["FirstName"], Key);
            $LastName = custom_decrypt($row["LastName"], Key);

            $array_new[] = array("Id"=>$row["Id"], "FirstName"=>$FirstName, "LastName"=>$LastName);
        }
```

Then to search, I inserted an if statement before my $array_new[] line, that checks to see if my search form has been posted, then sets a variable/flag if it has and there is a match between the search and the name variables. Then I wrapped an if statement around my $array_new[] line, so that it only add that data to the array it if there is a match.

I also set the variable/flag if there was no post variable, so it would return all items if a search didn't happen.

Lastly, I sorted my array after the while loop using:

```
        usort($array_new, function($a, $b){ return strcmp($a["LastName"], $b["LastName"]); });
```